# Fixed CSS element moves page down when input focused in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am having a little UI issue and cannot work it out.

On an iOS device, when I click in the input QTY value on the fixed buy element at bottom, it shifts the whole page to the bottom.

CSS:

```
.product-bottom-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 14px 2px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;

  ul {
    margin: 0; 

    li a span {
      display: block;
      font-size: 0.4em;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: -6px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }

  .zopim-call-chat {
    float: left; 
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .sticky-add-to-cart {
    float: right; 
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    padding: 3px 22px 9px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .sticky-add-to-cart i {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    top: 2px;
    left: -3px;
  }

}

.sticky-qty div.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

@media #{$mobile-breakpoint} {

  .product-bottom-sticky {
    display: block;
  }

  .sticky-chat {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    background: #555555;
  }

  .sticky-qty {
    float: right;
    width: 31%; 
    padding-top: 7px;
  }

  .sticky-qty label {
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
  }

  .sticky-qty .quantity-input {
    width: 31%;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 7px;
  }

  .sticky-add .button-add-to-cart {
    background: #f14fa1;
    border-color: #f14fa1;
  }

  .sticky-add,
  .sticky-out {
    float: right;
    width: 52%;
    padding-top: 7px;
  }

}
```

### Update

I found a partial solution here:

https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/05/20/mobile-safari-scrolling-problem-with-an-input-field-inside-a-fixed-div/

CSS:

```
html,body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

This fixed the issue but created another issue: when I click the tabs it scrolls to the top.

### Update 2

This is my JS which seems to be conflicting - maybe as it's using body, html. Is there a way to sort it since the input fix I added? It just seems to jump to the top of the tab on changing the tabs.

JS:

```
function scrollToTab(x) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(x).offset().top - 10
  }, scrollSpeed);
}
```

Comment: This is expected iOS behaviour when zooming.

Comment: Understood, but surely there is a JS or JS fix / work around for this...

Comment: Its nothing to do with zooming though?

Comment: https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/05/20/mobile-safari-scrolling-problem-with-an-input-field-inside-a-fixed-div/ - this solution works but then breaks the tabs on the page, when you click one of the accordion tabs it scrolls to the tab lol